# Fix "The Eclipse Installer executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."

Tags: eclipse, installation

I'm trying to install Eclipse Neon on a 64 bit Windows 7 computer. I download the file "eclipse-inst-win64.exe" and run as administrator. Immediately I get the following error:

```
The Eclipse Installer executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

Note the "Installer" keyword. When searching on Google and StackOverflow, I find solutions only for when receiving this error launching Eclipse itself **after** it is installed. The solutions that worked for people in those situations usually involve editing the "eclipse.ini" file and removing absolute paths or references to uninstalled plugins. However, Eclipse has never been installed on this computer, therefore an "eclipse.ini" file does not exist and the installer does not appear to create one in any obvious place before throwing this error. There does not appear to be any "companion shared library" downloads on the Eclipse website. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the JDK and then try to install Eclipse again.

According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation:

> Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) was released on June 22, 2016. See Neon schedule.
>   Consider using the Installer. Please see 5 Steps to Install Eclipse.
>
> A **Java 8 JRE/JDK** is required to run all Neon packages based on
>   Eclipse 4.6, ***including the Installer***. The reasoning behind
>   requiring Java 8 are discussed here.

**I found another reason for this error message.** I got it when I tried to install Eclipse from the compressed installer. I extracted the installer into a folder and ran it from there. It then installed.

Try to extracted all the installer files before you run the installer.